# Import all from current package

Tags: python

I have a package like so:

```
lib/
    __init__.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
    framework.py
```

My `__init__.py` is structured as such:

```
__all__ = ['module1', 'module2']

def run_all():
    for module in __all__:
        eval(module).Bot().start()
```

Each module is a small program that will be run from a larger one, and the `run_all()` function was created to easily do that.

If I import each module individually, like so:

```
from lib.package import module1
from lib.package import module2
```

everything works as it should. Although, if I try to import all:

```
from lib.package import *
```

or even like this:

```
from . import *
```

I get a NameError that the package is not defined.

How can I import the modules inside the package for `run_all()` to work?

**EDIT**

When I add `from . import *` or `from lib.package import *` to `module.__init__.py` (or even nothing at all) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 64, in <module>
    Bot().start()
  File "./main.py", line 45, in start
    package.run_all()
  File "/home/bkvaluemeal/Documents/bot/lib/package/__init__.py", line 16, in run_all
    eval(module).Bot().start()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module1' is not defined
```

Comment: Please show us the exact text of the error.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./master.py", line 64, in <module>
    Bot().start()
  File "./master.py", line 45, in start
    package.run_all()
  File "/home/bkvaluemeal/Documents/bot/lib/package/__init__.py", line 16, in run_all
    eval(module).Bot().start()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module1' is not defined`

Comment: That exception (which should really be edited into the question, rather than unformatted in a comment) is from when you don't import the sub-modules at all (which is unsurprising). Can you show the exception you get if you do `from . import *` or `from lib.package import *`?

Comment: That's the error for everything. The only way I have made it work is by importing `from lib import package` and `from lib.package import *`.

The first loads `run_all()` into memory and the second all the modules.

Comment: My question is if it works in master, why can't I move it to __init__?

Comment: Wild guess: The modules are being loaded into your `main` namespace, but not into your `package` namespace, because you used `import *`.  Is that the specified behavior of `import`?

Comment: @Kevin That's what I'm noticing. It's as if `run_all()` is not in the module, but in `master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your run_all function.
It iterates over a list of strings (`__all__`) and tries to eval them.
You'll might want to use `__import__` or `import_module` instead (haven't tested the below code myself but it should work) ...

```
def run_all():
    for module in __all__:
        mod = __import__("lib.package", globals(), locals(), [module], -1))
        getattr(mod, module).Bot().start()
```

or

```
import importlib

def run_all():
    for module in __all__:
        mod = importlib.import_module("lib.package.{}".format(module))
        mod.Bot().start()
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Perhaps my file path is wrong? I've noticed that imports behave like their in the same directory as the calling class. Is __import__ importing from `/home/bkvaluemeal/Documents/bot` or `/home/bkvaluemeal/Documents/bot/lib/package`.

Comment: That doesn't work in 3.x.  All imports are absolute except `from .foo import bar`.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this correct: `__import__` does not work in v3.5, the version that I am using, yes?

Comment: This seems to work: `__import__('lib.package.' + module, globals(), locals(), module, 0).Bot().start()`, but I don't understand what it's doing. Is there a way to simplify it?